# Как проверить на число псевдомассив arguments?

Tags: javascript, функции

Прошу помочь разобраться)
Как проверить на число псевдомассив arguments?

```js
function avg() {
  let sum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arguments[i]; i++) sum += arguments[i];

  return sum == 0 ? sum : sum / arguments.length;
}

console.log(avg(1, 2, 3, 'f'));
```

Comment: Можете добавить больше информации, что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: вроде и так работает все. `Number.isInteger()`

Comment: @entithat А если число не целое попадется?

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите отсеять даже строки с числами, оставив только аргументы с типом числа, и не учитывать при делении неправильные аргументы, можно попробовать так:

```js
function avg(...args) {
  let sum = 0;
  let validArgumentsCount = 0;

  for (const arg of args) {
    if (typeof arg === 'number') {  // ◄◄◄
      sum += arg;
      validArgumentsCount++;
    }
  }

  return sum === 0 ? sum : sum / validArgumentsCount;
}

console.log(avg(1, 2, 3, 'f'));
```

Код примера использует копирование содержимого объекта `arguments` в массив `args`, используя [rest-оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) - этот современный способ считается более эффективным: как минимум [в некоторых случаях](https://github.com/vhf/v8-bailout-reasons) он улучшает производительность, помогая избегать побочных эффектов реализации JS-движка, а также обладает рядом полезных особенностей (они указаны в статье на MDN).
Синтетический тест быстродействия: https://jsben.ch/JmU9F

Comment: спасибо большое, задача была просто оставить аргуметы с типом число

Comment: _«можно ещё заменить arguments на rest parameters, этот современный способ считается более эффективным»_ - А в чем именно тут заключается эффективность создания промежуточного массива `args`, какие преимущества он дает в данном случае? **p.s.:** Это называется rest-оператором, он применим не только к параметрам.

Comment: @yar85 Некоторые практические преимущества перечислены, например, на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters#the_difference_between_rest_parameters_and_the_arguments_object). Что касается эффективности, насколько я помню, некоторые нюансы использования `arguments` приводят к деоптизмизации кода в V8 (возможно, разработчики уже это исправили, не знаю): смотрите, например, первые две причины в [vhf/v8-bailout-reasons: A list of Crankshaft bailout reasons with examples](https://github.com/vhf/v8-bailout-reasons).

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, уточняющий вопрос был не о "некоторых", а о _вполне конкретных_ преимуществах в рамках задачи вопроса. Прочти внимательнее, пожалуйста: _«в чем именно **тут** заключается эффективность создания промежуточного массива args, какие преимущества он дает **в данном случае**?»_. Этот момент достаточно важен, т.к. ответ по сути говорит "применяйте rest-оператор", но не поясняет его роль в решении задачи.

Comment: @yar85 Я не имел в виду в данном случае, я имел в виду общий совет: мол, лучше привыкать использовать то, что имеет меньше потенциальных побочных эффектов и больше возможностей. В данном конкретном случае, скорее всего, разницы нет. Прошу прощения, если это было неясно.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, теперь ясно. Спасибо за объяснение! Я добавлю улучшающую правку, если ты не против, т.к. этот ответ по идее должен стать принятым (как предлагающий код строго сфокусированный на поставленной задаче - в отличие от моего, с альтернативным вариантом разрешающим типкасты).

Comment: @yar85 Да, конечно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть удобно учитывать не только изначально числовые значения, но и значения которые могут быть представлены числом:

```js
function avg() {
  let [count, sum] = [0, 0];
  for (let value of arguments) {
    if (!(isFinite(value = +value))) continue; // пропуск итерации если числовое представление аргумента не является конечным числом (унарный оператор `+` приводит к типу `number`)
    sum += value; 
    ++count; 
  }
  return count && (sum / count);    // в случае нулевого значения `count`, вернется 0 (т.к. логический оператор И возвращает свой левый операнд когда тот является ложным, а `Boolean(0) === false`) 
}

console.log(avg(1, 2, '3', 'f'));   // значение '3' будет обработано как число!
```

**Следует учитывать** очевидный нюанс: помимо строкового представления чисел, к `number` могут успешно приводиться булевые значения, массивы, объекты типа `Date`, и т.д.. Если такое поведение нежелательно, то к проверке на пропуск значения аргумента (кроме конечности его числового представления) можно добавить доп. условие вида `String(converted) !== String(value).trim()`, где *converted* это переменная со значением `+value`. Это условие пропуска по сути будет означать игнорирование всех значений которые не являются числом или строковым представлением числа.